# Configure: передача параметра и значение параметра по умолчанию

Tags: c, компиляция, autoconf, autotools

Необходимо, чтобы в файле configure.ac была переменная "XXX". При этом, необходимо, чтобы у нее было значение по умолчанию и возможность установить значение, при вызове ./configure. Т.е., чтобы можно было сделать что-то такое:
если вызывается `./configure`
используется значение XXX по умолчанию (пусть будет "ааа")
если вызывается `./configure XXX="bbb"`
значение XXX становится "bbb"
Никак не пойму, как для этого необходимо описать файл configure.ac

Comment: сразу встречный вопрос, какого рода переменная? среды? Makefile'а? define?

Comment: ну, я эту переменную собираюсь передавать в макрос `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([mydefine],[XXX],["desr"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOO=${FOO:-foo}
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([FOO_MACRO],[$FOO],["Desriprion"])
```

Судя по всему всё что не раскрывается макросом из `configure.ac` просто поадает в скрипт `./configure`. Поэтому для установки переменных можно использовать обычный [синтаксис](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) POSIX `sh`.

Можно также задавать значение прямо в макросе, хотя в этом случае есть свои подводные камни с интерпретацией кавычек.

```
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([FOO_MACRO],[${FOO:-foo}],["Desriprion"])
```

Также ИМХО хорошим тоном будет объявить эту переменную [AC_ARG_VAR](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html#index-AC_005fARG_005fVAR-1030).

Comment: Странное дело, выглядит так, будто действительно должно было сработать, однако в итоге, при обращении к `FOO` в макросе `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED`, возвращается пустая строка, не важно, передавалось в итоге значение извне, или нет.

Comment: @АндрейСолодовников, гм... вроде проверял — сам удивился. что работает, но больше воспроизвести не могу.... поправил ответ, теперь уж точно должно быть всё правильно и [работать](http://paste.debian.net/1030759/).

Comment: Да, благодарю, теперь работает!